# How to use printf to print out all precision of double float number

Tags: c

I want to keep all precision of double number.
I try to use this to keep it in text file.

```
printf("%g", double_value);
```

And I want to convert it to double

```
double_value = atof(string_read_from_file);
```

I found it lost precision when I use printf, what's the correct method?

Comment: The question this has been marked as a duplicate of has mediocre quality or rambling answers. A simple answer is you can use `printf("%.*g", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, double_value);`. The `.*` in `%.*g` says to use the next argument as the number of digits to print. `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is the number of decimal digits needed to guarantee the printed string has enough digits to reproduce any original `double` value when converted back to `double`. It is defined in `floatl.h`.

Comment: BTW, when using C99 (or newer) one can use `"%a"` to always print perfectly round-trip-able, albeit not-so-human-friendly, representation.